# Create three specified APNs for each mobile providers - automatically add APN

Tags: android, apn

How do I automatically add APN?

We have 3 mobile service providers (those providers will be get from inserted SIM cards & local carriers not listed in global) - ProA, ProB and ProC.
We also have specified APNs for each providers -

For ProA,
name : a1,
APN : apn1

For ProB,
name : b1,
APN : apn2

For ProC,
name : c1,
APN : apn3

--

I would like to add 3 buttons for each APNs to add preferred APNs when clicking buttons.

How do I write the code and edit it in the manifest file?

Comment: In general, it is agreed here that [you shouldn't use greetings or salutations in your posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276033/pointless-question-edit/276037#276037). They get in the way of us readers figuring out the actual question. I've edited them out for you this time.

Comment: sorry for my inconvenience greetings & my poor in english. Thanks for editing & reminding me.